# Не добавляется элемент в XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq2xml

Не добавляется элемент в XML-базу.
Пробую так:

```
XElement user = new XElement(username);
XAttribute timeto_ = new XAttribute("TimeTo", "");
XAttribute chatid_ = new XAttribute("chat_id", chatid.ToString());
user.Add(timeto_);
user.Add(chatid_);
users.AddFirst(user);
db.Save("data.xml");
```

db - создано в классе `public static XDocument db = XDocument.Load("data.xml");`.
users - главный элемент `public static XElement users = new XElement("users");`.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вы можете выкинуть из вопроса всё лишнее и оставить только тот код, который не работает? И описать чего вы ожидаете от этого кода и что фактически происходит

Comment: @АндрейNOP изменил, если Вам так угодно

Comment: Что такое `db` и что такое `users`, как они между собой связаны?

Comment: Напишите, что вы хотите получить (структуру XML файла как пример результата). И код полностью, чтобы было понятно откуда все переменные.

Comment: @Rootware, выше в комментариях было: `Вы можете выкинуть из вопроса всё лишнее и оставить только тот код, который не работает?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Писал на коленке (нужна оптимизация). Поддерживает единичную запись и добавление нового узла:

```
string[] array = {"Sasha", "Masha", "Natasha"};

foreach (string username in array)
{
    Boolean exists = File.Exists("data.xml");

    XDocument xdoc = exists ? XDocument.Load("data.xml") : new XDocument();
    XElement list = exists ? (xdoc.Element("users") == null ? new XElement("users") : xdoc.Element("users")) : new XElement("users");

    XElement user = new XElement(username);

    XAttribute timeto_ = new XAttribute("TimeTo", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss"));
    user.Add(timeto_);

    XAttribute chatid_ = new XAttribute("chat_id", "1");
    user.Add(chatid_);

    if (list.HasElements)
        list.AddFirst(user);
    else
        list.Add(user);

    if (exists)
        xdoc.ReplaceNodes(list);
    else
        xdoc.Add(list);

    xdoc.Save("data.xml");

    MessageBox.Show("Added: " + username);
}
```

Результат (конечный):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <Natasha TimeTo="17.06.2018, 15:11:24" chat_id="1" />
  <Masha TimeTo="17.06.2018, 15:11:23" chat_id="1" />
  <Sasha TimeTo="17.06.2018, 15:11:22" chat_id="1" />
</users>
```

Т.к. автор не описал суть своего кода. Возможно многое можно выкинуть или что-то придётся добавить. Очень хорошее описание работы с XML документами в примерах кода и результата для [System.Xml](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.2.php), для [System.Xml.Linq](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.5.php).

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать: как лучше сделать проверку на то есть элемент в users или нету? Если нету, то код выполняется

Comment: @Hol0ZeN не поленитесь и почитайте по ссылке описание. Там полный разбор документа и его свойств. Оттуда и возьмёте то, что вам необходимо.

Comment: По ссылке работа с XmlDocument, а у автора (да и у вас в ответе) используется XDocument

Comment: @Rootware кстати, элемент так и не хочет добавляться и теперь приложение вообще не запускается, выдает ошибку _Не удается добавить в содержимое знаки, отличные от пробела_

Comment: @Hol0ZeN: *как лучше сделать проверку на то есть элемент в users или нету?* — `users.Element(...)` - если он есть, то он будет возвращен, иначе возвращается null. Ну и лучше не создавать элементы с названием, которое вводит пользователь, т.к. это очень ненадежно. Лучше создавать, например, элементы `user`, а имя хранить во вложенном элементе или атрибуте.

Comment: @Rootware проблема с запуском решена, остался один вопрос: элемент так и не добавляется

Comment: @Hol0ZeN, приведите минимальный пример на котором проблема воспроизводится. Я вот написал код из трех строк и он работает нормально. Может у вас вообще проблема не там, например, `data.xml` заблокирован на запись? Создайте пустой проект и проверьте без всего лишнего. После этого опубликуйте нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @АндрейNOP если читать последовательно, то через 4-5 страниц идёт вариант для LINQ. Если это критично, то [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.5.php) нужное место.